# i am having some problem getting the return data of next auth credentials, anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to do a credentials auth with next-auth and Lark. But I can't get the return value of credentials,so does anyone know where did i go wrong ?

this is my nextAuth file

```js
// [...nextauth.js]
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { code } = credentials;
       const response = await fetch(
          `http://localhost:3000/api/handleLarkLogin`,
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              code: code,
            }),
          }
        );

        const result = await response.json();

        if (result.ok && response) {
          return result;
        }
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/token",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session(session, token) {
      session.user.code = token.code;
      return session;
    },
  },
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

and this is my sign in site

```js
// auth/token/index.js

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    try {
      
      const signInResponse = await signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false,
        code: data,
      });

      if (signInResponse.ok) {
        console.log(signInResponse);
      } else console.log(signInResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("error", error);
    }
  };
```

and this is my handleLarkLogin site

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const code = await req.body;
  const codex = JSON.parse(code).code;
  const Url =
    "https://open.larksuite.com/open-apis/auth/v3/tenant_access_token/internal";

  const rest = await fetch(Url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      app_id: "my code",
      app_secret: "my code",
    }),
  });

  const repo = await rest.json();

  //=============================== get tenant access token =================================
  const Urli = "https://open.larksuite.com/open-apis/authen/v1/access_token";
  const resp = await fetch(Urli, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      Authorization: `${repo.tenant_access_token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      code: `${codex}`,
      app_id: "my code",
      app_secret: "my code",
    }),
  });

  const result = await resp.json();
  res.status(200).json(result);
}
```

how to get the return value of credentials
Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is in this line inside the `session` callback:

```js
session.user.code = token.code;
```

here `token.code` is `undefined` so `session.user.code` will be `undefined`.

to fix this you have to add the `jwt` callback inside the `callbacks` object just before the `session` calback :

```js
async jwt = ({user, token}) {
  // here "user" is the object returned by the "authorize" function of the "CredentialsProvider" 
  // so it is in fact "result"
  if (user) {
    token.code = ...; // add the property "code" to "token" maybe user.code
    // you can add other stuff to your token
  }
  return token; // return the updated token
};
```

now when the `session` callback runs `token.code` should contain the expected data